# Kata 1.6.2 dependency chain broken

Tags: kata-containers

Kata 1.6.2 release page here:
https://github.com/kata-containers/runtime/releases/tag/1.6.2

We are trying to consume the latest stable-1.6 release of kata but are hitting the dependency error below when attempting to install the package.

```
$ sudo apt install kata-runtime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kata-runtime : Depends: kata-linux-container (>= 4.19.34.33-4) but 4.19.28.31-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/x86_64:/stable-1.6/xUbuntu_16.04/
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEmWR.png

Comment: This has been fixed by kata-containers team. Tracking item: https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers/issues/41

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question. You can download the latest package based on the fixes identified in [1.6.2](https://github.com/kata-containers/runtime/releases/tag/1.6.2). In particular, this [fix](https://github.com/kata-containers/runtime/commit/2de40227ee062f4fa6d5d4db193ea990fbc45876).

You can always download the 1.6.2 package too: [kata-static-1.6.2-x86_64.tar.xz](https://github.com/kata-containers/runtime/releases/download/1.6.2/kata-static-1.6.2-x86_64.tar.xz).